# How to pass grabbed values in JSP to Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Consider the following JSP :

```
<!-- Client's Page - permissions  -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Product Inventory Program</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/bar.css"
      type="text/css"/>           
</head>

<div id ="right" class="bar">
<a href="loggingOut">LOG-OUT</a> 
</div>

<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Client's page - Please choose one of the options below</th></tr>
</table>
<body>

<h1>Hello ${name.firstName} ${name.lastName} , You've logged in successfully!</h1>
<h1>
Please choose one of the following options
</h1>



<!-- Client Transactions -->
<fieldset>
  <legend>View all the products in the store</legend> 
  <form action="blablabla">
    <a href="clientAction1">Press here to continue</a>    
  </form>
</fieldset>


</body></html>
```

I have a Servlet called `clientAction1` :

```
package controller.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import db.DatabaseInventory;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Client1_before
 */
@WebServlet("/clientAction1")
public class Client1_inventory extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        synchronized(session) 
        {
            String grabbedNameAndLastName = request.getParameter("nameAndLastName");
            // do something with 

            // uncomment this code if you want to use a for loop 
            // ArrayList<String> inventory = null;

            String inventoryStringVersion = null;

            DatabaseInventory myDatabase = new DatabaseInventory();
            try 
            {
                myDatabase.initiateConnection();        // open connection 
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

            try 
            {
                // uncomment this code if you want to use a for loop
                // inventory = myDatabase.getInventoryProducts();
                inventoryStringVersion = myDatabase.returnInventoryWholeString();
            } 

            catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            // uncomment this code if you want to use a for loop
            // request.setAttribute("inventoryList", inventory);

            request.setAttribute("inventoryBigString", inventoryStringVersion);

            // forwards to the page employeeOpenNewAccount.jsp
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/results/client"
                    + "/client1_seeInventory.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to pass the fields `${name.firstName}` and `${name.lastName}` from the JSP to 
my Servlet .

How can I do that ?

Comment: There *aren't* any "existing fields". You get values from a JSP to a servlet by submitting them.

Comment: Dave is correct - the standard here is to submit them along with your form. If you already have the static values on the page, they might as well be in hidden inputs.

Comment: @CraigOtis: How do I make them hidden inputs ?

Comment: @ron hidden input `<input type='hidden' id='firstname' value=${name.firstName}>`

Comment: @CraigOtis: Great , please put it as an answer and I'll choose that as the best answer . I didn't know about hidden input . Much appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, for this we can use hidden input:

```
<input type='hidden' id='firstName' value=${name.firstName}>
```

But since you don't want to use `<input>` tag, you may try as below:

```
<a href="clientAction1?firstName=${name.firstName}&lastName=${name.lastName}">
```

Comment: While possible, the OP already has a `<form>` listed on his page. It seems much less syntax-prone, and much easier to read, to just use hidden inputs. Plus, it avoids using servlet expressions.

Comment: yes, but I suggest this since OP don't want to use any `<input>` tags

Comment: @RafaEl : In anchor tag missing `=` after `&lastName`. You can use `<a href="clientAction1?firstName=${name.firstName}&lastName=${name.lastName}">` Don't use scriptlets.

Answer (score 1):

you can keep these values in session as these values are related to session information of a person and are send when the user login . Then these values will be send back each time a request is send to the server and session is maintained.